# How many CouchDB databases per application?

Tags: couchdb

In SQL databases data is organized around tables. In CouchDB there are no tables. How would data of a single application be organized in CouchDB? Single database where many documents are simply thrown and then using views to group data that serves same purpose? Or multiple databases (doesn't sound right, but seen this in some projects) treated as SQL tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most things, it depends on your application requirements. Using a single database can be simpler, but not always.

I've seen people use a single database with multiple design documents, each defining their own views relevant to a specific type of documents. This allows multiple types of documents to co-exist in a single database. A single database makes the backup strategy vastly simpler.

I've seen multiple databases used to group things logically by user/group/account. If keeping data clearly silo-ed and separate is important, this could be attractive. Another benefit to this approach is that you can more easily implement custom logic between different types of customers/accounts. (of course, with the trade-off that things can drift between all those disparate databases)

There is no "right answer" to this question, like I said before it depends on your application's needs. I would start with a single database, but be open to switching to multiple if it feels like a better fit for your data. CouchDB is flexible like that :)